# Data type mismatch in access user selection form

Tags: ms-access

I'm creating an Access form where the user will select a team name from a drop down and it will provide all the details of that team name.

In the VBA code to get the form to reload in accordance to the users selection I keep getting a data type mismatch.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the field Team Name a string? If yes use single quotes around that value

Comment: @Steve I've changed to TeamName = "Select * from Current_Headcount where ([Team Name] = ' " & Me.TeamName & " ')" However now when I select the name from the user form, there is nothing displayed in the datasheet below

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues.

If TeamName is a “text” column, then you need to surround the text with quotes (use single quotes in this case).

Hence the following should work:

```
TeamName = "select * from Current_Headcount where ([Team Name = '" & me.TeamName & '")
```

Comment: I've changed the code to the following                                                    TeamName = "Select * from Current_Headcount where ([Team Name] = ' " & Me.TeamName & " ')" However now when I select the name from the user form, there is nothing displayed in the datasheet below